# What / where is "all arch" specified when building a .deb archive

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'm trying to make some .deb files for Ubuntu and the new Debian. When I run the method that worked in the past, there are several comments in the ouput. I would like to fix any issue but I can't understand the error, nor find an example of a fixed code on the net.

These are the command and comments:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
.... all ok and then ....
dh_testdir: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_testroot -i
dh_installchangelogs  -i
dh_installchangelogs: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_installdocs -i
dh_installdocs: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_link -i
dh_link: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_compress -i
dh_compress: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_fixperms -i
dh_fixperms: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_installdeb -i
dh_installdeb: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_installdeb -i
dh_installdeb: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_shlibdeps -i
dh_shlibdeps: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_gencontrol -i
dh_gencontrol: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_md5sums -i
dh_md5sums: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
dh_builddeb -iv
dh_builddeb: You asked that all arch in(dep) packages be built, but there are none of that type.
```

This driver works when I compile the source and install it without making a deb package, but after building the debs they will not install. module-assistant cannot find the kernel source.

[These are the instructions I used:](https://github.com/iocellnetworks/ndas4linux/wiki/How-to-build,-install-and-remove-.deb-ndas-packages#wiki-Download_and_build) They worked in the past.

Comment: Please show your `debian/control` and `debian/rules` file for that package.